# JBoss Application Server on Rackspace Cloud/Mosso

Tags: web-server, ip, cloud-computing, jboss, rackspace

So,I have a cloud account with Rackspace Cloud. I've set up a server with them. They gave me an IP and a password. I SSH'd to the machine, installed Mysql-server, Java and JBoss 5.0.1. I started JBoss on port 80 by modifying the server.xml in the JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/ directory. I start JBoss server with a EAR deployed, which deploys without errors. I've tested this EAR on my local instance of this same server. In fact, by "install" I meant "tarred up, scp'd and untarred on the cloud server."

After starting the server, with seemingly no problems, when I point to the IP in my browswer, I get an unable to connect error. I'm expecting JBoss's default management stuff to show up. I also tried several different pages in my deployed EAR and go the same thing.

I'm really, really new at this. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Please make sure,1 there is no default firewall blocking your port, 2 try to telnet to port 80 on localhost just to make sure you are getting through, then do the same remotely.  You can start there, but in your text there is not enough info to know what exactly you are doing wrong. Thanks for your question

Comment: I'm not really a sys-admin and although I understand theoretically why I should do these things you mention, I have little clue as to HOW. :D Could you point me at some resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem on my own, fortunately. Checking the IP Tables on your fresh Rackspace Cloud server might solve your problems if you encounter something similar to the question asked.